# Co Authoring in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, document-library, co-authoring

We are trying to configure co-authoring on one of the doc libraries. We open a Word 2013 Docx document in one PC and try to open the same document on another PC.

But instead of collaboration we get a `"document is locked by another user for editing"` message.

Both the users have contributed permission on the library.

Comment: which office version user are using office 2013 or office 2016?

Comment: we are using Office 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To enable `co-Authoring`, the feature `check in/out` must be turned **off**.
- `Co-Authoring` works only in Word, power point, one note in both client application and office web application.
- For Excel, co-Authoring works only in the Office web application (edit file in the browser).
- If the issue persists, look in the control panel for Credential Manager.

  - Select the entry for the web application URL in Credential Manager and delete it by selecting `remove from vault`.
- If the issue persists again, follow this [guide](http://www.sharepointindepth.com/sharepoint-prompts-for-credentials-three-times-followed-by-a-blank-white-page/#credman) to clear the cache of the credential manager